# how to show only Y status on my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to show only one status in a field:

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Docentry ORDER BY t.linealog) FILA
from (select docnum, docentry,Confirmed as confirmado,UserSign2 as usuario,ObjType as tipodoc ,UpdateDate,UpdateTS as Hora,LogInstanc as linealog
from adoc
where ObjType=17
union all
select DocNum, DocEntry,Confirmed,UserSign2,ObjType,UpdateDate,UpdateTS,99 from ordr
) as t
order by DocEntry, FILA
```

this give me this output:

[image: Output1]

You can see ndoc in this case 1: give me 4 rows, i just want 2,only Y, I did it with this:

```
with mycte as (

select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Docentry ORDER BY t.linealog) FILA
from (select docnum, docentry,Confirmed as confirmado,UserSign2 as usuario,ObjType as tipodoc ,docdate,UpdateDate,UpdateTS as Hora,LogInstanc as linealog
from adoc
where ObjType=17 
union all
select DocNum, DocEntry,Confirmed,UserSign2,ObjType,docdate,UpdateDate,UpdateTS,99 from ordr
) as t

),

mycte2 as (

select m.*, coalesce(m2.confirmado,'N') confirmadoanterior from mycte m left join mycte m2 on m.fila+1=m2.fila and m.fila=1 )

select * from mycte2 where confirmado='Y'  and confirmadoanterior='N'  

order by docnum
```

I just want the line with status ' Y' coming from status 'N' In this case only the row 10.

This is the expected result:
 [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqGJ7.png)

what kind i do to filter Y status too?

thanks.

Comment: if you have images to share aobut the issue, embedded those in the question so we can see it without going to another site.

Comment: *"But Now i have new problem, with status Y:"* > what exactly **is** that problem?

Comment: @TT. I just want to show only the  Y status,  when the rows come from N status,  no Y to Y only N to Y

Comment: You need to provide that information **inside your question**, not in the comment section. You can edit your question by clicking the `edit` link. Do that and add that information in your question.

Comment: @Used_By_Already done! I put my expected output. thanks

Comment: great, but I don't have time to carefully compare 2 images - how does image 2 differ to image 1?. plus: don't link to images put them into the question itself (like you did before) and: need "sample data" in a reusable format (text) or as inserts or prepare a http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

Try filter for [Confirmed] = 'Y' inside the UNION ALL query. e.g.

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
      SELECT
            *
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Docentry ORDER BY t.linealog) FILA
      FROM (
            SELECT
                  docnum
                , docentry
                , Confirmed AS confirmado
                , UserSign2 AS usuario
                , ObjType AS tipodoc
                , docdate
                , UpdateDate
                , UpdateTS AS Hora
                , LogInstanc AS linealog
            FROM adoc
            WHERE ObjType = 17 AND Confirmed = 'Y' --<< HERE
            UNION ALL
                  SELECT
                        DocNum
                      , DocEntry
                      , Confirmed
                      , UserSign2
                      , ObjType
                      , docdate
                      , UpdateDate
                      , UpdateTS
                      , 99
                  FROM ordr
                  WHERE Confirmed = 'Y' --<< & HERE
            ) AS u
     ) AS d
ORDER BY
      docnum
```

If this isn't what you are looking for could you please provide "sample data" and "expected result".

Comment: thanks! I posted a asnwer yo you, with the expect result!, really thanks. @Used_By_Already